# Can you add two SECTION sections to ld script

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors, ld, linker-scripts

I have an executable made by linking several .o files, using a somewhat involved linker script.   If a particular environment flag is set, I'd like there to be another section involved.   So, something like:

```
/* withfoo.ld */
SECTIONS {
 .foo 0x80000000 : {
    _start_foo = .;
    . += 0xfff;
    _end_foo = .;
 }
}
```

and then compile with:

```
if [ $FOO_DEFINED ]; then
    gcc -Wl,-T normal.ld $(OBJS) foo.o foo.ld
else
    gcc -Wl,-T normal.ld $(OBJS)
fi
```

where I'd like to not to have to modify `normal.ld`.   `normal.ld` has a SECTIONS definition within it.   So that gives me two SECTIONS...  I'm getting the warning:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: foo.ld contains output sections; did you forget -T?
```

Is there an actual problem or is this just a warning?  Also is there a proper way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU linker scripts and LD do not support conditional compile. You can't use two linker scripts at once and have it work as expected. You have to pre-process the linker script with some other type of macro language like `m4` or even just use the GNU C Preprocessor `cpp`.

---

Not sure if this is a type of solution you are looking for. The *C* preprocessor `cpp` can process the text of any kind of file (even non-C files) and will blindly parse for pre-processor directives and macros just like a *C* file. You can also pass *C* style defines through the `cpp` command line just like you can with *GCC*. You create a linker script with all the *C* pre-processor directives and generate specific linker scripts based on that. For example create a special linker script like this:

`linker.ld.pp` :

```
SECTIONS {
#ifdef FOO
 .foo 0x80000000 : {
    _start_foo = .;
    . += 0xfff;
    _end_foo = .;
 }
#endif
}
```

This uses typical *C* style `#if/#ifdef/#endif` for conditional compilation. If you run it through the *C* pre-processor with a command like:

```
cpp -P -DFOO linker.ld.pp
```

You'd get output like this:

> ```
> SECTIONS {
>  .foo 0x80000000 : {
>     _start_foo = .;
>     . += 0xfff;
>     _end_foo = .;
>  }
> }
> ```

Not defining `FOO` would be done like this:

```
cpp -P linker.ld.pp
```

The output would be:

> ```
> SECTIONS {
> }
> ```

To redirect the pre-processor you can output to a linker script with:

```
cpp -P -DFOO linker.ld.pp >withfoo.ld
cpp -P linker.ld.pp >withoutfoo.ld
```

You can specify multiple `-D` directives on the *CPP* command line to define multiple pre-processor symbols if you wish. The idea of this method is that you have a single linker script but you create a shell script to generate the necessary specialized scripts that are required.

---

### Other Observations

Usually you specify linker scripts on the *GCC* command line with the `-T` option:

```
gcc -T withfoo.ld $(OBJS) foo.o
```